# Download and save a file in Windows Metro App

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have an C# which downloads files from the internet, saves them, open and read them and copy them.

The code looks something like this

```
private static void DownloadSpec()
{
    Debug.Print("Downloading Spec...");
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(CompletedSpec);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://myurl.ul/spec"), @"spec");
}

...
...
...
isNewSpecPresent = File.Exists(@"spec");
...
...
file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"./download/spec");
...
...
File.Copy(@"spec", @"./download/spec", true);
```

But things like WebClient, File, Debug.Print, DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs seems to be not available in a Windows Metro App.

So, how can I achieve the same thing in a Windows Metro App?

Is there a porting guide available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [localFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) store for app specific storage. Then you can use the  `StorageFile`, `FileIO`, and `CachedFileManager` classes to help you out. Also, use the `await` keyword when running async methods.

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.txt", 
   CreateCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, result);

var status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);

if (status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
{
    var md = new MessageDialog("done");

    IUICommand x = await md.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: It works... A little bit :) How can I store the file inside my 'applicationfolder'?  Using ´GetFileFromPathAsync("myFile.txt");´ lead to an exception because relative paths are not allowed.